# dyld: Library not loaded for a Framework within a Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8

I am trying to embed a Framework that are using another Framework and this works just fine in the simulator, but it crashes on an iOS device:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FrameworkB.framework/FrameworkB
>     Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/B072CD7C-8595-4AE4-A506-26832A0F4402/FrameworkTest.app/Frameworks/FrameworkA.framework/FrameworkA
>     Reason: image not found

This is my structure in Xcode:

- FrameworkTest.xcodeproj (the app project)

  - FrameworkA.xcodeproj (Cocoa Touch Framework)

    - FrameworkB.xcodeproj (Cocoa Touch Framework)

The app (FrameworkTest) uses a class `A` from FrameworkA (which is embedded in the FrameworkTest app). The class `A` uses the class `B` from FrameworkB (which is linked in FrameworkA).

This works just fine in the simulator, but it does not work on the device.

The structure may seem a bit strange, but I am developing the frameworks as I go when I develop the app, which is why I want to add the framework projects inside my app project.

I have uploaded the [project on GitHub](https://github.com/iDealDevTKC/FrameworkTest) for you to see, if you need to take a closer look. (The class `A` is invoked in the AppDelegate.m file)

Why is this working in the iOS simulator and not on the device? And how can I make it work on the device?

**EDIT:**

As simonthumper suggests in the comments, I have also tried to add `FrameworkB.framework` to `Copy Files` as Frameworks destination in Build Phases for FrameworkA, but that gives me this error in the console:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FrameworkB.framework/FrameworkB
>     Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/2A38A2BC-9CD7-4AF6-9E50-42C16D92D6B2/FrameworkTest.app/Frameworks/FrameworkA.framework/FrameworkA
>     Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>       /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/2A38A2BC-9CD7-4AF6-9E50-42C16D92D6B2/FrameworkTest.app/Frameworks/FrameworkA.framework/Frameworks/FrameworkB.framework/FrameworkB: mmap() error 1 at address=0x10012C000, size=0x00008000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/2A38A2BC-9CD7-4AF6-9E50-42C16D92D6B2/FrameworkTest.app/Frameworks/FrameworkA.framework/Frameworks/FrameworkB.framework/FrameworkB

Comment: Have you got the framework in the copy files build phase?

Comment: @simonthumper I have edited the question with more information if I do that :-)

Comment: Hi. I am also facing same kind of issue. But i don't have second framework project code with me (only FrameworkB.framework  i have). Any idea how do i go about it ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I contacted Apple with this issue and found a solution to my problem. Apple's Technical support made it clear, that I need to add the FrameworkB.xcodeproj to my application project, so my project structure is:

- FrameworkTest.xcodeproj (the app project)

  - FrameworkA.xcodeproj (Cocoa Touch Framework)

    - FrameworkB.xcodeproj (Cocoa Touch Framework)
  - FrameworkB.xcodeproj (Cocoa Touch Framework)

When I have done this the application project can include FrameworkB.framework as an Embedded Library:
[image: FrameworkTest.xcodeproj build phases]

This solved my problem and made it possible to run it on an iOS device.

**If the build crashes on Release:**
Revoke your Enterprise Distribution certificate and create a new one to solve the problem. Once I did that it worked perfectly.

Comment: Hi. I am also facing same kind of issue. But i don't have second framework project code with me (only FrameworkB.framework i have). Any idea how do i go about it ?

Comment: +1 But this shouldn't be a solution - how can we build single-file SDKs if so :-( Any updates to the situation as of date?

Comment: Solved my issue, thanks. Anyhow, are we not adding frameworkB twice? I would compare with a solution in which it is not added (allegedly) twice, but I don't have it...

Or is Xcode intelligent enough to add it only once? I'd like to believe that since they are frameworks (dynamic shared libraries, right?), the first time frameworkB is added to frameworkA, only the reference is copied. However, when frameworkB is added to frameworkTest, the code is copied, not the reference. Am I right?

Someone point me in the right direction to understand this, please :)

Answer (score 6):

I also had similar issues with embedded frameworks and I just tried your code from GitHub.

**Option 1** (not suitable for teamwork)

What made the error disappear was to add FrameworkB to *Embedded Binaries* in the *General* tab of your *FrameworkTest* target.[image: xcode - embedded binaries]

**Option 2**

Well, sharing project with other developers sure is important :). Did you try this approach? Add *New Copy Files Phase* In the FramewrokA's *Build Phases* and add FrameworkB into Frameworks destination.
[image: new copy phase]

But I'm not sure why does it work on the simulator. If anyone knows, please, feel free to comment.

cheers

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried adding FrameworkB to Embedded Binaries too, and that works. But it links directly to the `DerivedData` directory, which isn't what I am after. This will only work on your Mac. I am sharing the project with other developers, so this needs to work without any specific paths. :-)

Comment: @ThomasClemensen I just read your edit so my second solution is bad for you as well ...but it did work for me (using your project)

Comment: @micromanc3r I've tried your second Option 2 but this giving me error.

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FrameworkB.framework/FrameworkB
  Referenced from: ......FrameworkTest.app/Frameworks/FrameworkA.framework/FrameworkA
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
 .....FrameworkTest.app/Frameworks/FrameworkA.framework/Frameworks/FrameworkB.framework/FrameworkB'

Comment: Option 2 is awesome compared to "embed swift standard library" option in other answers regarding that kind of problem