# dyld: Library not loaded, framework within framework

Tags: xcode, swift, build, frameworks, ios9

I am trying to use a custom Framework that using 3 other 3rd party Frameworks like Alamofire. When i try to run it on a device i get this error (works fine in the simulator):

> dyld: Library not loaded: /Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
>     Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9A745A5D-2778-4E69-8971-9CCBFE8D4B79/MyApp.app/MyApp
>     Reason: image not found

I looked on many similar error but nothing work.

Tried the solution for very similar [error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28872151/654327) with no luck.

Embed binaries, Copy files, Clean, Restart nothing works.

Xcode 7 with ios 9 and El Capitan, swift 2.0.

HELP