# Embed frameworks inside a framework iOS

Tags: ios, frameworks, xcode7

I have a project containing another target(framework) which is a dependency of the main project. That framework requires it's own frameworks, so I've added them using carthage. The project compiles and runs fine on simulator, however I'm getting the following error when running it on a physical device:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Subframework.framework/Subframework
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/LONG-ID/MyApp.app/Frameworks/MyAppSDK.framework/MyAppSDK
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/LONG-ID/MyApp.app/Frameworks/MyAppSDK.framework/Frameworks/Subframework.framework/Subframework: mmap() error 1 at address=0x00798000, size=0x00060000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/LONG-ID/MyApp.app/Frameworks/MyAppSDK.framework/Frameworks/Subframework.framework/Subframework
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740268/dyld-library-not-loaded-for-a-framework-within-a-framework), however the only solution is to add the Subframework to "Embed frameworks" to top level project, which is not viable. I've tried modifying Build Settings -> Linking -> Dynamic Library Install name, however it didn't help.

How can achieve make it work on the iphone?

Comment: I would look at setting the runpath of the framework.  I assume we are talking about iOS 8+?

Comment: @trojanfoe yes, the minimum version is iOS 8, where and to what should I set it to?

Comment: it's in the build settings.  You probably just need to add `@loader_path`, assuming both frameworks are in the same directory.

Comment: @trojanfoe the loadersdk of the Myappsdk already points to loaderpath, along with the rpath

Comment: OK so it's time to investigate the app bundle and look at the current location and settings of the frameworks to ensure they are right.  It's strange it works on the simulator but not the device though...

Comment: I've checked thoroughly, and the "MySDK" framework file contains the required subframeworks inside

Comment: Any progress on this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, the same issue persists

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue for some time and I had a three level hierarchy where the outer most 'Umbrella Framework' should not be distributed with the other frameworks. How I resolved it was by setting the 'Run Search Paths' under 'Linking' in 'Build Settings' of each of the 'Umbrella Framework' to point to the 'Copy Files' destination that is set in the 'Build Phases' (You have to add a 'Copy Files' build phase and preferable set its' destination to 'Frameworks', then add each 'Sub-framework' you want to embed).

[Copy sub-framework to 'Frameworks'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryXCq.png)

[Set 'Runpath Search Paths' to 'Frameworks'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zoav6.png)

Comment: After having this arrangement in my application, the Application Loader refused to upload the ipa with error messages: 'ERROR ITMS-90205: "Invalid bundle. The bundle at 'appname.ipa/Frameworks/umbrellaFramework.framework' contains disallowed nested bundles".' and 'ERROR ITMS-90205: "Invalid bundle. The bundle at 'appname.ipa/Frameworks/umbrellaFramework.framework' contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'".'. I ended up letting the umbrella framework be compiled with the sub-frameworks and move the sub-frameworks out it after compilation and embed them to the project. Also delete 'Frameworks' dir.